# memory usage by different techniques

Tags: c, memory

```
enum{
   OFF,
   ON
  }

#define OFF 0
#define ON  1

int /char  ON=1,OFF=0;
```

I want to know if there is any difference in memory usage by the three methods I used above. Please if anyone knows the answer let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
int /char  ON=1,OFF=0;
```

You can check size of `int` and `char` yourself, with `sizeof(ON)` / `sizeof(OFF)`. `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte, while `int` is typically 4 bytes, but it may be different on different platforms.

```
#define OFF 0
#define ON  1
```

This does not use any memory at all, as the substitution is performed during preprocessing part of compilation.

```
enum{
   OFF,
   ON
}
```

This only declares type, and not a variable. As for actual memory usage, you'd need to declare variable of such type and check it with `sizeof`. It is guaranteed to be at last size of an `int`.